# How can my desktop visit a mobile site that automatically redirects?

Tags: redirect, mobile, firebug

I'd like to use Firebug to check out the markup for a mobile site m.somesite.com  The problem is that when visiting the site from the desktop, the site automatically redirects to the desktop somesite.com

Is there a way to tell a site that you're mobile device (though you're really a desktop) in order to avoid this redirect and let my desktop see m.somesite.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These article might help you: http://mobiforge.mobi/testing/story/testing-mobile-web-sites-using-firefox?dm_switcher=true (may be it is outdated in details, but idea is the same)